# How to search within a Twitter user's likes

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

In Twitter, is there an operator that allows you to search within a user's likes? Perhaps something like `likes:username` or `list:username/likes` etc.?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Ok. I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the question, but what you need is very easy to do with TweetDeck.

1. Enter https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/
2. "Add Column" button
3. "Likes" option
4. You can select your own user or another one you want. Press "Add Column" button to confirm.
5. Once you have added the column there are options to filter tweets, such as search terms among others. Remember that this column is already filtering only the Liked Tweets:
   [image]

Comment: Ah, this is very useful indeed; no misunderstanding there. I was hoping something simpler for basic Twitter search existed but I guess it doesn't, and this is simple enough.

Comment: I can only filter recent tweets with this filtered column. Not more historical ones.

Comment: This solution works perfectly as of today, but unfortunately there's a new design via TweekDeck Preview, and I could *not* replicate this functionality there. Likes is not a column option.

Comment: @SilverSideDown As of today at least it's still possible. The easiest way I found was to click on an account. This should open a profile view with icons at the bottom. Click the Likes icon, then click Add Column. That said, flurdy's comment seems correct—this doesn't search all likes.

Comment: I realize it's `case sensitive` when I got empty results. It is a waterfall, some old item are not easy to come out

Answer (score 8):

**[Twitter's advanced search](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-advanced-search)** does not support such an option, but you can try some 3rd party like:

- **https://www.favourites.io/**
- **http://www.tweetattackspro.com/**
- **https://ifttt.com/**

You can also use **[Twitter's API console tool](https://developer.twitter.com/en.html)** by authenticating through Twitter in the browser and providing your handle and userid.

The last resort would be to use Twitter directly:

- type the name of the user whose favourites you want to see into the top search box. If you want to view your own favourites, click the **Favorites** link on the right side of the screen and jump to the last step
- click the user's name on the right side of the screen under **People results**
- open the **Favorites** tab which will display all tweets the user has made a favourite
- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>F</kbd>** and type in a keyword to search the favourites on that page (if a match is found, the favourite will be highlighted)

Comment: Snapbird had a free option that worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use the API console thing?

Answer (score 5):

The proper way of doing it would require writing code. The "dirty" way of doing it is as follows:

1. Install the [**Autoscroll**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/kgkaecolmndcecnchojbndeanmiokofl) extension on your Chrome browser
2. Navigate to the users's Likes page: `https://twitter.com/{username}/likes`
3. Click the **Autoscroll** extension button (<kbd>**⬇⬇**</kbd>) to automatically refresh all the likes effectuated by the desired user (may take some time depending on how many likes that user has)
4. Use Chrome's built-in page search <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**F**</kbd> to search within the likes

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work for me. I have over 500 likes. I can scroll to the bottom to load them all into the page. If I am at the bottom and search for something in the top tweet, it can't find it. It only finds it when I'm pretty close to the top. Likewise, I can only find something towards the end of the page if I'm near there in my scroll position. I'm not sure whether this is a problem with Twitter or the browser, but the behavior was consistent in Chrome in Firefox.

Comment: what you can do is to run the browser search <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**F**</kbd> before you begin scrolling and leave it on. While **Autoscroll** will run, new search matches will appear and increase the count in the searchbox as you go along.

Comment: Now that Twitter is dynamically regenerating / resizing browser contents on scrolling actions, Control-F only works for a limited window of items.